# Second activity has a grey status bar

Tags: android

I have a problem with using translucent status bars.

On my first activity it works perfectly:

[image]

When I open a new activity it looks like this:

[image]

Layout for my first acctivity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MyActivity">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay_list_tool"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<include

    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/lay_list_tool">
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_content"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Layout for my second activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
style="@style/AppTheme.Base"
tools:context="net.maartengeelen.mybar.SearchResultsActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_result_tool"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/search_result_tool"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my style used in both activities:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/divider</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Can somebody tell what I'm doing wrong? To me this should be exactly the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284219/notification-bar-is-grey-after-implementing-nav-drawer

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't work. Besides then my status bar is not translucent anymore

Comment: `style="@style/AppTheme.Base"` this attribute is not present in your first activity

Comment: declare the same theme for both activities in manifest..

Answer (score 0):

add same style theme for second activity in manifest file.

like this:
    `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">`